# How to perform queries using unsupported search fields?

Tags: stripe-payments

Using [Stripe's Search API](https://stripe.com/docs/search), I want to query customers by balance, e.g.:

```
query: "balance>0"
```

However, with  reviewing available [Query fields for customers](https://stripe.com/docs/search#query-fields-for-customers), this query is not possible. Error message:

```
"Field `balance` is an unsupported search field for resource `customers`."
```

Why not?
Is it possible to perform queries with unsupported search fields?

Comment: _"Why not?"_ would be a question for Stripe's developer support. _"Is it possible to perform queries with unsupported search fields?"_ is trivially: no, that's what unsupported means.